# NullPointerException in MediaStore insertImage function in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, mediastore

I have a production app which is running in more than 1000 devices. One of the feature is to take bitmap of an image view and share it via all shareable apps. For achieving this , I have created the bitmap and inserting it via Media Store , then getting the URI and passing it in Share intent.

```
private void createAndShareImage() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String shareMgText;
        shareMgText = "Read this post";
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMgText);
        String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), ImageUtil.getBitmapFromView(postImageView), "", "");
        if (url != null && !url.isEmpty()) {
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to create shareable image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Select the app"));
    }

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            if (v.getMeasuredHeight() < IntegerConstants.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            else
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            v.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ImageUtil", e.getMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

This code was working fine for long and I haven't changed this code. But suddenly I have started getting crashes from couple of  Android 10 devices. The Firebase crashlytic log says :

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: url
> at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:133)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1951)
> at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:1794)
> at com.xxxx.yyy.dialogs.SharePostDialog.createAndShareImage(SharePostDialog.java:121)
> at com.xxxx.yyy.dialogs.SharePostDialog.onClick(SharePostDialog.java:99)

And this happens in RedMi Note Android 10 devices ( at least in my test devices Android 8 and Android 11 this is not reproducible). I am unable to understand any possible cause of the issue. What and how it is getting null ? And how it can be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
> inserting of images should be performed using MediaColumns#IS_PENDING, which offers richer control over lifecycle.

For 29> you have to use `ContentValues` and `ContentResolver`, as shown below:

```java
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String shareMgText = "Read this post";
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
shareMgText);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
    ContentValues valuesimage = new ContentValues();
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/");
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1); 

    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver(); 
    Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    OutputStream fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri);
    Bitmap savedBitmap = ImageUtil.getBitmapFromView(postImageView).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos); 
    fos.flush(); 
    fos.close();

    valuesimage.clear();
    valuesimage.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
    resolver.update(imageUri, valuesimage, null, null);

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Select the app"));

} else {
    String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), ImageUtil.getBitmapFromView(postImageView), "", "");
    if (url != null && !url.isEmpty()) {
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Select the app"));

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to create shareable image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I suppose you are referring resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, valuesvideos);   I have tried this code and I am getting the following error in this line only...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory Images not allowed for content://media/external/images/media; allowed directories are [DCIM, Pictures]

Comment: So I tried Relative Path as "Pictures/" and it is inserting the image. But I have a new problem now. I am not able to access this image while sharing. It gives an error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only owner is able to interact with pending item content://media/external/images/media/36"

Comment: Thanks, it worked in 1 device. Let me test in few more devices and will get back with the update.